# calling two versions of nodejs with different names

Tags: zsh, node.js

I have two version of nodejs installed. One in `/users/anaconda/bin/` and another by homebrew

Now I want to use both NodeJS versions. I want to use conda version using `conda-node` and homebrew version using `node` command in terminal

How can I possible write some bash code that handle these two exports?

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew makes symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` etc. (On my Mac, I've renamed `/usr/local/bin/node` to something else, in case you want to have several versions there as well)

If you want to keep the Homebrew-variant as `node`, just add

```
ln -s /users/anaconda/bin/node /usr/local/bin/conda-node
```

and you'll be able to type `conda-node` in a terminal.

These are not "exports", and you don't need "bash-code" - they are symlinks from a directory that is already in your `PATH`.